# Using the matrix function as a collector

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to use the matrix as a container for all observations of CD resulting in a 20 by 3 matrix in my simulation for the data frame below;

```
Nsimdata=function(ns,tp,mu,sigma2){
   x1=rnorm(ns)
   x2=rnorm(ns)
   x3=rnorm(ns)
   U=c(x1,x2,x3)
   simdata=data.frame(CD=U,ID=1:ns,
                   Time=factor(rep(c(1,2,3),each=ns)),
                   treatment=sample(rep(c('Trt','placebo'),ns/2)))
   #ans[k,]=table(simdata$treatment)
   simdata
}
```

So this is what I've done

```
ns=20
nsim=2
tp=3
YK=matrix(0,nrow=ns,ncol=tp)
for(i in 1:nsim){
   DD=Nsimdata(ns,tp,mu,sigma2)
   for(j in 1:tp){
      Y=subset(DD,Time==j,select=c(CD))
      Y=Y$CD
      X=c(rep(0,ns/2),rep(1,ns/2))
   }
}
```

I want to get all the observations under CD in my data frame into YK. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried?  Does `matrix(DD$CD, ncol=3)` work for your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Why not write the simulation function the way you want the data to end up?

```
# function to simulate the data
fnSimData = function(iSampleSize, iT, dMu = NULL, dSigma2 = NULL) {
  mU = matrix(rnorm(iSampleSize*3), ncol = 3, nrow = iSampleSize)
  simdata = data.frame(outcome.time = mU, 
                       idx = seq.int(iSampleSize),
                       treatment = sample(rep(c('Treatment','Placebo'), iSampleSize/2)))
  return(simdata)
} 

# parameters
iSampleSize = 20  # sample size
iNumSim = 2  # number of simulations
iT = 3  # number of time periods

# simulate the data
fnSimData(iSampleSize, iT, dMu, dSigma2)
```